# Localizable DisplayName attribute for class level

Tags: c#, localization, attributes

I am looking for a way to set a displayname attribute at a class level which is localizable. I managed to fix the it for the method/property level using the display attribute:

```
       [Display(
            ResourceType = typeof(HardwareLocalization),
            Name = nameof(HardwareLocalization.DoorAccessConfiguration_RequireActiveMembership_Name),
            Description = nameof(HardwareLocalization.DoorAccessConfiguration_RequireActiveMembership_Description)
        )]
        public bool RequireActiveMembership { get; set; }
```

But `[Display(Name = 'x')]` is not applicable at a class level, only `[DisplayName('name')]` is, but that is not localizable.

I have been searching around, but all posts I find only tackle the problem at a method/property level.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to derive a new attribute class with a different parameter.

Using the following definition, you can provide a resource name as the parameter.

```
internal class ma_DisplayNameAttribute : System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute
{
  public ma_DisplayNameAttribute( string ResourceName )
    : base ( AttributeTest.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(ResourceName) )
  {
  }
}
```

Attribute test is the name of my component. You would have to replace it with base namespace in your component.

You can use it just like the original DisplayName attribute

```
[ma_DisplayName("Banana")]
class Class2
{
  ..
}
```

except that the parameter is now the name of the resource string.